# comparing values in separate columns

Tags: shell, text-processing, awk

I've got a `csv` that looks like this, (there are other columns but these are the pertinent ones)

```
region, city, actual rating, predicted rating
NSW, SYD, 0.765, 0.5
Victoria, Melbourne, 4.81225, 5.0
```

What I want to do is output region and city where the actual rating is not within the nearest `0.5`, i.e. it would output `NSW, SYD` because `0.765` is nearer to `1.0` than `0.5`. I've tried doing variations on `awk` to do this by figuring out the rounding:

```
awk -F, '{$3=$3*2; printf "%0.0f\n",$3}'
```

but I'm not sure how to preserve other fields when I'm editing a particular one so I'm stuck at this step

Comment: Please, provide an example of input and desired output.

Comment: Also, a real CSV will have quoted values, which may contain literal `,` commas. Look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1063125/linux-tool-to-parse-csv-files for instance to safely parse CSV files. Both ruby and python have CSV modules that make this easy and wrapper tools make it even easier.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Inferring from the data you show, the predicted rating is a multiple of 0.5, so the condition “the actual rating is not within the nearest 0.5” is equivalent to “the actual rating differs by more than 0.5/2”. So test that. Standard awk has no absolute value function so you need to combine two tests.

To print the first two fields, print `$1` and `$2`. Set `OFS` to a comma to have them comma-separated; alternatively you could use `print $1 "," $2`.

```
awk -F, -v OFS=, '$4 - $3 < -0.25 || $4 - $3 > 0.25 {print $1, $2}'
```